# Including newsletter block in a static block issue

Tags: magento-1, static-block, newsletter, cms-block, static-content

I tried to include the newsletter block in a static block content, like:

```
  {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

But it is not working. Can you give some ideas why and what else should I try ?

Thx

Comment: it is disabled. But if I write anything else in my static block (strings) , it is displayed except the newletter.

Comment: This should work, May be cache. Is there any CSS or something that hides newsletter block ?

Comment: @AnilSuthar There isn't :( The html content of the news block it is not generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Magento 1.9.2.4 or versions with last patches applied you have to allow permissions to blocks included in CMS pages/static blocks.

To do so go to **System > Permissions > Blocks** and click the Add permission button.

- Block type : newsletter/subscribe
- Allowed : Yes

Comment: Your answer is correct also for enterprise editions. In my case: 1.14.2.2  . Thx a lot